# Verify Ubuntu installable USB created by usb-creator

Tags: live-usb, usb-creator

Let's say I have an Ubuntu live USB pen drive, created using `usb-creator`. I want to

1. Verify the integrity of the Ubuntu install on the pen drive (only against accidental damage, not malicious changes).
2. Find out the Ubuntu flavour and version and architecture (eg, something like Kubuntu 14.10 amd64).

How does one do this?

I do not want to take the trouble of booting from the USB for either of these, of course. And other files may be stored on the pen drive too, they do not interfere with the live USB functionality.

Answer (score 2):

First identify your USB device with the command:

> lsblk

Lets assume it is /dev/sdb1

Now generate the MD5 hash code:

> sudo md5sum /dev/sdb

It will take some time. It will give a long code like:

> 69c2a3c0e7f4a209734e8531f1e5b771

Finally compare it with the the codes issued in [Ubuntu web site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes):

If the your hash code is different, probably your USB key is corrupted.

Comment: I use the pen drive to store other files too. They do not interfere with the live USB functionality. So the hash being different doesn't imply the USB key is corrupted. Also, if one has enabled persistence, then the hash will of course be different.

Comment: @Prateek: Then you can hash the Ubuntu system partition in the USB device. Your personal files go into a separate partition created specifically for persistence functionality. You can see the partitions with `lsblk` command

Comment: I see. I have never actually used persistence. However, I have only one partition on the pen drive, and it has files other than the Ubuntu stuff too. So hashing the partition won't work.